# Should our magic-the-gathering tag have subcategories?

Tags: discussion, tags, magic-the-gathering

As has been mentioned before the bulk of our questions are tagged [magic-the-gathering](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering).  Would there be any value in breaking this down into subcategories?  I'm not a MTG player so I'm not the person to pick the subcategories, but things like this could work:

- deck building
- card interactions
- buying and selling

Does this seem like a good idea?  What subcategories would you like to see?

Does this break any site rules about how tags are done? (*Apparently no, since they already exist!  Dur.*)

## Edit

Can I made this bad question any better by turning it into: **why aren't the more specific tags used more often?**  Does it make sense for most of the MTG question to be in the general tag and nothing else?

Comment: Are you seeing any specific problems caused by the fact that we don't have these subcategories? In other words, what is the problem that this proposal aims to solve?

Comment: Over half of the posts on the front page and in the weekly digests are about MTG and they all have the most general tag.  It seems like we could do a better job of bucketing these things so that people can find other related Q/A's.  Finding anything related in a bucket of 3000+ things seems more challenging that it needs to be.

Comment: The 3 subcategories you suggested could apply to many other games besides mtg which in the end would make them more of a meta tag.

Comment: They were just intended as examples, I hoped someone with deeper knowledge would have something better and it seems like that's already happened.

Answer (score 5):

We do have a fair number of more specific tags already, of the form "mtg-something" - go [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags) and search for "mtg" to see things like [mtg-commander](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-commander), [mtg-drafting](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-drafting), and so on.

Generally, we could add more tags in that vein if we think they're organizationally helpful, i.e. if the topic meets these criteria:

- people will likely want to search for and browse questions on that topic
- we have a substantial number of questions on that topic
- we don't have so many questions on that topic that it would be nearly equivalent to the main [magic-the-gathering](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering) tag.
- it will be intuitive and obvious how and when to use the tag.

Given that, I'm not too sure about the tags you've suggested:

- deck building and card interactions - given that we don't get a ton of play strategy questions, these two pretty much divide the topic into two pieces, deck building (i.e. outside actual play), and rules (i.e. during actual play). That makes them a bit less useful, since they're so broad, and even more importantly, it's pretty unlikely that folks posting questions will think to use these tags.
- buying and selling - we just don't get a lot of questions about this, so I don't see a lot of potential added value.

Comment: Thanks for showing me tags I missed.  I hadn't seen those used much so I hadn't noticed them.  I just used those bullets to give an idea of what I was talking about.